# How to get crisp lines after a render?

Tags: rendering

Apologies for being a newbee. I watched many tutorials but I cannot seem to find an answer on how to render even the default cube with crisp outer lines. I save the object as a .png with transparent background in order to import it into Adobe illustrator but the outer lines are aliased, not crisp. what am I missing?

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Aliased? Crisp? You might need to specify what you want blender to render with a picture or some figure. And why import png(pixel-based) to Illustrator? If the edge was not good, why not manipulate it in Photoshop?

Comment: Could you attach some images to your question to better show the results you have so far?

Comment: I rendered the default cube as a PNG test because I need a transparent background. I used the default setting in Blender 2.8 to see what the lines would look like once imported. My main layout is in Illustrator for printing purposes. I started out using Photoshop 3D but got stuck by its 2GB limit and an un-rendable scene. I discovered Blender and trying to rebuild my "Photoshop 3D" scene and noticed that the rendered default cube is not crisp after render. I am also stuck unable to leave the "CTRL+ALT+0" view.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that blender will render with some slight effects with Eevee.
If you use Eevee. Try changing under the render tab go down to film and change filter size to a lower number.
This might bring sharpness up to where you need it.

Let me know if that helps?
Cycles too has glossy which causes renders to blur slightly.
This might be the antialising your speaking of!

Just for kicks. Try rendering with cycles.
Or. Try opening older blender 2.79 and render with cycles.
2.79 has blender render might be what you need. A more simple render.

Answer (score 1):

I have no exact answer myself yet, but what did improve it.

By changing *Render > Film > Pixel Filter*  to *Box* or set the pixels to lower values but there will be a lot of stepping

Examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]